# Stop NestedScrollView inside ViewPager to process horizontal scrolls

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to implement a view that is composed by a CoordinatorLayout with a ViewPager, and the NestedScroolViews are inside each ViewPager. I managed to make the Toolbar hide on scrolls, but I've been having the following issue:

Whenever I swipe left or right to change the content of the view pager, the gesture is forwarded to the NestedScrollView that sometimes registers a very small vertical scroll. It is small, but enough to be annoying.

This should explain the problem better:

[image: Example of behavior]

Video: https://youtu.be/BGqynDDL68I

I've tried extending the NestedScrollView to block the scroll/fling methods but no success.

Has anybody gone through the same issue?

**EDIT 1 : Code**

Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="main.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/main__activitycontent"/>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main__toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main__fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout

        android:id="@+id/main__navigations_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/main__tabbar_button_color"
        app:layout_behavior="utils.views.TabLayoutBehaviour"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/main__tabbar_selected_color"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/main__tabbar_normal_color"
        >


    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment With ViewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/meditationpager__pager"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Inner Fragment:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="main.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/main__activity">

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="domain.screens.readmeditation.MeditationFragment">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/large_text"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Just a note: the bottom bar is not releted to the ViewPager, it is a navigation bar.

Comment: For what i can see the bottom bar has a "tick downward". am i right?

Comment: Yep, and the toolbar goes a little to the top as well (The behavior of the bottom bar depends no the toolbar, so when the toolbar moves, the bottom bar moves on the opposite direction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution I found was to extend the NestedScrollView and override the onTouch event like this:

```
public class VerticalOnlyNestedScrollView extends NestedScrollView {
    private static final String TAG = "VOnlyNestedScrollView";
    public VerticalOnlyNestedScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    private float startX, startY;

    public VerticalOnlyNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public VerticalOnlyNestedScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (!(ev.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)&& ev.getHistorySize() > 0) {


            float yVector = ev.getY() - ev.getHistoricalY(0);
            float xVector = ev.getX() - ev.getHistoricalX(0);
            Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent: " + xVector + "--" + yVector);

            return Math.abs(yVector) <= Math.abs(xVector) || super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This way, the parent onTouch is only processed if yVector is greater than the xVector.

Comment: It's working perfectly here with the exact same code. can you provide more context?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Activity's structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="main.MainActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--<include layout="@layout/main__activitycontent"/>-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main__toolbar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/meditationpager__pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/main__navigations_tablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/main__tabbar_button_color"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/main__tabbar_normal_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/main__tabbar_selected_color"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This way your fragment with the view pager would be no longer necessary and you could setup your view using:

```
private void setupViewPager() {
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    InnerFragment fragment = new InnerFragment();
    adapter.addFragment(fragment);

    mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I believe that with this approach, you wouldn't need to set your NestedScrollView's layout_behavior.